# Как понимать значение слова "атомики"

Tags: веб-программирование, терминология

Поступила задача реализовать небольшой проект. И вот такой комментарий:

> никаких скриптов только "атомики"

Как это понимать? Что имеется ввиду под "атомиками" ?

Comment: Лучше спросите у своего заказчика. А заодно и расскажите здесь.

Comment: Возможно имеется в виду атомарный дизайн? https://habrahabr.ru/post/249223/